# Setting up MySQL database behind a VPN address

Tags: mysql, xampp, vpn

I have a regular MySQL server running with XAMPP at port **3306** and accessible by my internet ip aswell my local ip (127.0.0.1), the ports are forwarded in my router. An account set up to be accessed from any IP, Everything works fine.

I'm trying to make this same server be accessible by AirVPN DNS address. So I've followed AirVPN instructions to remove the forwarded ports in my router and forward a new port at their VPN with a random number (lets go with **1111**) with local port as **3306** and DNS named as **xxx.airdns.org**

[So I open MySQL with XAMPP under port **3306**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMw0t.png), nothing changed in config file. I run the AirVPN port checker over 1111 and it signals as open. I also try at other sites that checks ports and signals open at **xxx.airdns.org:1111**

Though when I try to make a connection as usual it returns error (10060): `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.airdns.org' (10060)`

Resolutions I've tried:

1. Switch port values in MySQL config files matching with the ports open in AirVPN
2. bound address to VPN adapter `bind-address="10.6.114.48"`

   > repeated the options above in all different kind of port combinations and addresses
3. Disabled Firewall on Ethernet adapter of VPN as described [here](https://community.logmein.com/t5/Hamachi-Gamers-Group/Inbound-Traffic-blocked-check-firewall-settings/td-p/134642)

I couldn't achieve success in this task. I'm looking for some enlightment so I can understand the process.

**EDIT:**
The connection is set only to TCP protocol. A port check done through airVPN  and is registered at XAMPP & FIREWALL logs as accepted connections. Though trying to connect from a client I got no log from Xampp or Firewall, it gets timed out.

Comment: Hi perhaps see if maybe the ISP is blocking it?

Comment: Have you tried via an SSH tunnel? That's often far more reliable.

Comment: @IronMan About diagnosing an ISP connection blocking: `A good way to try to diagnose and solve this problem is by changing back and forth between servers to see if a different IP address does the trick or switch between ports or VPN protocols, if possible.` I have done that serveral times, I don't believe its the ISP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue**: Consider that you can't connect to a service running "*behind*" some `VPN server` from a machine that's connected to that very same `VPN service`.

**Solution**: Connect from another machine to test your service properly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for "answer" type not just comment, but i dont have enough reputation here :)

Maybe the protocol ( TCP/UDP ) is your issue.
If you use UDP on your airVPN better check forwarding on your router - most of them
by default sets TCP only. Otherwise maybe change to TCP on your airVPN. 
ISP provider often filter this protocol.

Comment: The connection is set only to TCP protocol. Also if I try a port check through airVPN site, it signals its open and my XAMPP&FIREWALL log also register the connection attempt and they do not reject it. But trying to connect from a client I got no log from Xampp or Firewall. It is strange to think that the ISP blocks the connection from one client but no the other and the router does the same.